# Error with running VcXsrv (xfce4) on Ubuntu 20.04 through WSL 2

Tags: 20.04, xfce, gui, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run GUI (VcXsrv) through WSL 2 on Ubuntu 20.04 as given in the [tutorial](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/04/16/windows-susbsystem-for-linux-xfce-4/), but I get the following error:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
xfce4-session: Cannot open display: .
Type 'xfce4-session --help' for usage.
```

I have added `export DISPLAY=:0.0` at the end of `.bashrc`, ran XLaunch prior to running ubuntu with 'disable access control' checked.

Comment: Did you *source* the modified .bashrc file (`. ~/.bashrc`) before attempting to start the xfce4-session?

Comment: i have tried, it didn't work

Comment: @Nmath true, but VMs use more resources and using WSL with GUI is possible (and works fine for me)

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

The issue is that the networking on WSL2 is more complex than on WSL, so if using WSL2, instead of typing `export DISPLAY=:0.0` at the end of `~/.bashrc`, type

```
export DISPLAY=$(awk '/nameserver / {print $2; exit}' /etc/resolv.conf 2>/dev/null):0
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
```

Credit: cppdvl on github